# JavaScript Parcel Error - Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot find module 'gkKU3'

Tags: javascript, import, export, parceljs, parcel

I learning JavaScript, and I trying to use Parcel and separate my code with MVC architecture.

I have problem with import class from my createAccView.js.

Error in console is:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot find module 'gkKU3'
at newRequire (createAccount.850bd9e5.js:61:19)
at newRequire (createAccount.5ab67b3e.js:53:18)
at newRequire (createAccount.ea3edc65.js:53:18)
at newRequire (createAccount.5ab67b3e.js:45:18)
at localRequire (createAccount.5ab67b3e.js:84:35)
at parcelHotUpdate.7Gu71 (createAccView.js:1:1)
at newRequire (createAccount.5ab67b3e.js:71:24)
at hmrAcceptRun (runtime-a1bda32dadeb9347.js:563:3)
at ws.onmessage (runtime-a1bda32dadeb9347.js:147:13)
```

CreateAccView.js code:

```
export class createAccount {
  #fullName = document.querySelector("#fullname");
  #userName = document.querySelector(".username-input");
  #email = document.querySelector("#email");
  #password = document.querySelector("#password");

  create() {}

  checkName() {
    const nameArr = this.#fullName.trim(" ").split(" ");
    if (nameArr.length >= 2) {
      return true;
    } else {
      this.showError("Check your Full Name. Must be two words.");
      return false;
    }
  }

  checkUserName() {}

  checkPassword() {}

  showError(msg) {
    const errorContainer = document.querySelector(".error-container");
    const errorMsg = document.querySelector(".error-message");

    errorMsg.textContent = msg;
    errorContainer.classList.add("error-active");
    setTimeout(function () {
      errorContainer.classList.remove("error-active");
    }, 3000);
  }
}
```

controller.js code:

```
import { createAccount } from "./views/createAccView.js";

// const newAcc = new createAccount();

// console.log(newAcc);
```

Files tree:

[Files Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6Ne2.png)

Comment: Have you managed to solve this problem?